# How to extract nouns from a German text with the StanfordNLP tool in Scala?

Tags: scala, maven, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to extract the nouns of a German text with the StanfordNLP tool. Therefore I added the dependencies for German texts.

---

My dependencies:

```
     <dependency>
                <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
                <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!--BEGIN: NLP For German Text -->
        <dependency>
              <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
              <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
              <version>3.6.0</version>
              <classifier>models-german</classifier>
            </dependency>
            <!--END: NLP For German Text -->

            <!-- Other dependencies -->
```

In my Scala class I want to extract the nouns of a tweet. Here the following code snipped:

```
// Start a new processor to use the NLP tools
    val proc: Processor = new FastNLPProcessor

    // TODO: Explain the val doc
    val doc = proc.annotate(text)

    // Is a String where the keywords are stored that we want to extract (e.g. Nouns - "N"; etc.)
    var keywords: String = ""

    // Iterate throgh each sentence
    for (sentence <- doc.sentences) {

      // i - contains the word of each sentence in a text in the current loop
      // x - saves the position of the word in the current loop
      // E.g. for tweet text :: "new scala update xyz" -> first loop: i = new ; x = 0
      for ((i, x) <- sentence.tags.get.view.zipWithIndex) {
        // "N" - is the abbreviation for Nouns
        if (i.toString().startsWith("N")) {
          // Append to keywords the noun of a text
          keywords = keywords + " " + sentence.words.array(x)
          // Print the current state of the keyword string
          println(keywords)
        }
      }
    }
```

But it only works for english texts. These are my imports:

```
import org.clulab.processors.Processor
import org.clulab.processors.fastnlp.FastNLPProcessor
import play.api.libs.json._
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoConnection
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBObject
import org.clulab.struct.DirectedGraphEdgeIterator
```

---

**The complete Scala class:**

```
object KeywordExtractor {

   // Creates a connection to the MongoDB client
   val mongoConn = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)

   // Names the DB where the data should be saved
   val mongoDB = mongoConn("dbtest")

   // Defines the collection in which the text should be stored
   val mongoColl = mongoDB("testcollection")

  def extractKey(tweet: String) = {

    // tweet is sent as a Json-String. jsonObject -> stores the sent tweet as a Json Object
    val jsonObject = Json.parse(tweet)

    // text String to store the text from the tweet
    var text = ""
    try {
      // try to parse the text from the jsonObject into the text variable
      text = (jsonObject \ "text").as[String]
    } catch {
      case e: JsResultException => println("Limit reached")
    }

    // Start a new processor to use the NLP tools
    val proc: Processor = new FastNLPProcessor

    // TODO: Explain the val doc
    val doc = proc.annotate(text)

    // Is a String where the keywords are stored that we want to extract (e.g. Nouns - "N"; etc.)
    var keywords: String = ""

    // Iterate throgh each sentence
    for (sentence <- doc.sentences) {

      // i - contains the word of each sentence in a text in the current loop
      // x - saves the position of the word in the current loop
      // E.g. for tweet text :: "new scala update xyz" -> first loop: i = new ; x = 0
      for ((i, x) <- sentence.tags.get.view.zipWithIndex) {
        // "N" - is the abbreviation for Nouns
        if (i.toString().startsWith("N")) {
          // Append to keywords the noun of a text
          keywords = keywords + " " + sentence.words.array(x)
          // Print the current state of the keyword string
          println(keywords)
        }
      }
    }

    // Create a new MongoDB builder
    val builder = MongoDBObject.newBuilder

    // Creates a monogDb object to store the keywords (a bison file is created and text is the key for the value keywords)
    builder += "text" -> keywords

    // TODO: .result not clear
    val newObj = builder.result

    // Insert the new Object to the MonogDB
    mongoColl.insert(newObj)

    // Clear the memory of the doc to avoid a out of memory error (doc allocates a lot of memory)
    doc.clear();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, as of 8/2016, the CLU Lab Processors library does not support multiple languages (see this [issue](https://github.com/clulab/processors/issues/56)).
The authors have not prioritized adding new languages but are interested in adding it if other have the time.

Note that you can tell the vanilla CoreNLP POS Taggers to use the German model by [changing the properties of the `StanfordCoreNLP` object](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/human-languages.html).